# I am not able to capture the web3 Error: Given parameter is not bytes: "0xue"

Tags: web3js

```
//Error: Given parameter is not bytes: "0xue"
//let a = true

myContract.methods.functionName(a).send({
    from: result[0],
    gas: 4700000,
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

my web3 version is `1.0.0.beta.35`

Comment: looks like you have an extra `}` after `console.log(result)`. Please share these: your contract method `functionName` signature ( it's from your contract, right? ) , and exact `send` argument values, i.e. what's in `result[0]`

Comment: result[0] will be the account address. here functionName(a) should get bytes32 values as input. If it gets other than bytes32 web3 is throwing the error Given parameter is not bytes. I am not able to capture the following error in the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you're catching now is lets you catch exceptions from async calls, i.e. when `.send({from...})` returns you a promise. But if `functionName` gets a wrong parameter, the remote call doesn't even start, so you need to catch it differently.

Try this:

```
try {
    myContract.methods.functionName(a).send({
        from: ...
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
    })
} catch(err) {
   //process the argument-related error here
}
```